# BigInteger Library

Tags: c++

I have a c++ BigInteger library. I have to create a bigInteger with exact 125 bit from any large random number. I need to perform rightshift, leftshift, setbit, getbit, NOT, OR, XOR, AND operation on created 125 bit number. Which library i need to use to do above operation? Can anyone please help me.

Comment: GMP is one of the more well-known ones.

Comment: Do you *have* a library or do you *need* a library?

Comment: I have used https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/.
But i cant create exact 125 bit Big number from any random number. If any other library can create the number then i need it or if possible to create big 125 bit number from this library then please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search with the terms `big integer library` gave me the [C++ Big Integer Library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) . From the website:

> This library emphasizes ease of use and clarity of implementation over
>   speed; some users will prefer GMP, which is faster.

**Edit:**

To create a random number with 125 bits there are plenty of options.

A simple and quick solution (but obviously not available in the library I posted above - I don't whether it's possible with GMP) would be to do a `rand() * 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` in the correct notation.

A method in the scope of the above library, which unfortunately is rather slow, would be to draw 125 single bits ("0" or "1" at random) and add increasing powers of 2 if you drew a "1". Here is some (untested) code:

```
BigInteger summand, number125bit;
summand = 1;

srand(systemtime_or_any_other_number);
for (int i=0; i<125; i++)
{
    if (rand() && 1)
    {
         number125bit += summand;
    }
    summand = summand << 1;
}
```

Comment: I used same above mentioned library (https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/)  but with use of this i unable to create a number exact 125 bit.

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully cover your question.

Comment: Random number is system time in milisecond. I need 125 bit bigInt from that random number. Please help me if any way to do this.

Comment: -1 for not being able to ask clear questions. The system time in ms won't give you 125 bits of independent information, so it's simply not suitable for generating a random number of 125 bits length. You will have to fill in about 100 bits with something else. If zeros are fine, you can simply left-shift the system time.

Comment: In java                                                              'BigInteger b = new BigInteger(125, random Number);'                    give the BigInteger number object with exact 125 bit.                             In cpp any way to do this?

Comment: In this case, your random number just acts as seed to a random number generator. You can set a seed for C++ `rand` function via `srand`. See my edits above.

Comment: I write the code like                                                   'BigUnsigned *b= new BigUnsigned(myBlocks, 1);
 
 srand( time(NULL) );
 int randomNumber = 249279711582393;//rand();

 b>setBlock(3, randomNumber);'                               but it not work. I cant get exact 125 bit

Comment: Thanks a lot.                                                                Above code gives 125 bit number

Comment: I have problem while left shift.

Comment: I have problem while left shift.                                           'BigUnsigned n1;

for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++)
 {
  if (i < 5)
  {
   n1.setBit(i,true);
  }
  else
  {
   n1.setBit(i,false);
  }
 }


BigUnsigned n2;
 n2 = n1;
 n2.bitShiftLeft(n2 , 40);'                                    It gives value of n2=0. But actual value is 34084860461056.